# tracking linux-firmware.git and backwards kernel compatibility

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, firmware, compatibility

I've been tracking the upstream Linux firmware repo in `/lib/firmware` on a couple of machines, doing very periodic updates of that tree.

I *think* I saw a firmware loading error booting an older kernel on the machine where I did a git-pull last week.

Does that repository have a policy about backwards compatibility with older kernels, or is that a non-issue (e.g.) because all the kernel does is load a binary file onto the target device using a standard interface that probably hasn't changed since a long time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the policy/guideline in the kernel source code package as `Documentation/driver-api/firmware/firmware-usage-guidelines.rst`, or here:

https://docs.kernel.org/driver-api/firmware/firmware-usage-guidelines.html

> ### Firmware Guidelines
>
> Users switching to a newer kernel should *not* have to install newer firmware files to keep their hardware working. At the same time updated firmware files must not cause any regressions for users of older kernel releases.
>
> Drivers that use firmware from linux-firmware should follow the rules in this guide. (Where there is limited control of the firmware, i.e. company doesn't support Linux, firmwares sourced from misc places, then of course these rules will not apply strictly.)

It then goes on with some details with how to handle the versioning of firmware in various common situations.

Comment: Thanks. In short there should be no backwards INcompatibility issues with firmware included in the official linux firmware tree(?)

Comment: Exactly. Note that it says newer kernels **should** work with older firmware, but new firmware files **must** work with older kernels. Your situation matches with the highest-priority requirement, so you should be as safe as you can possibly be.